# Creating table with select clause

Tags: hive

I'm trying to create a table using the CTAS style (Create As Select.
Hive gives an error if there is no data found in select query.

I tried something like this,

```
from 
(
select A.a,B.b from A join B on A.v=B.d
)tmp

create table test
as
select tmp.a,tmp.b
where tmp.a=100
```

**Note: there is no data matching tmp.a=100**

So,is there any way that can deal with this situation!
I mean, if data found in select clause a table is created, otherwise, it should not create the table or should not throw any error or it should create a empty table

Comment: May i know the reason for downvote!!!

Comment: I didn't downvote, however, your question is hardly understandable. I would try to rewrite but I've a hard time to figure out what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the question with sample code, but sadly i'm not able to do it

Comment: Much better now, thanks for the example

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is actually to create the table and use an insert from. It is also more resilient against mistakes, which is why this form is imho preferable in any case (c.f. static typing in programming languages)

However, it should also possible that you UNION your select clause with a table containing a single line and remove the line afterwards. Something along

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS 
( SELECT id,value from BAR)
(SELECt "-1" as id, -5 as value);

DELETE FROM foo WHERE id=-1;
```

(Not proper sql but the idea is hopefully understandable)

If you want just to create the table you can do

```
CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar;
INSERT INTO ...
```

the insert might again throw an error (don't have HIVE running here).

Comment: Good idea but i don't think we can remove a record from hive table

Comment: Sorry was for a moment thinking about standard RDMS. In Hive this can only be done using partitioning. But as said: wouldn't be my preferred solution.

Comment: Also added Create Like which might help here.

Comment: In my case there is no similar table, so couldn't use LIKE